# How to transform a row in a column based on duplicated data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, conditional-aggregation

I have been trying to do this since a while now but haven't been successful so far.

I'm currently trying to translate a row into a single cell of another row in SQL Server.

Example:

I have 4 rows:

| ID | Account | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | John | 23.0$ | 2022/06/22 |
| 02 | Travis | 14.0$ | 2022/06/22 |
| 03 | John | 00.0$ | 2022/06/22 |
| 04 | Travis | 12.0$ | 2022/06/22 |

The result intended is this one :

| ID | Account | Value1 | Value2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | John | 23.0$ | 00.0$ | 2022/06/22 |
| 02 | Travis | 14.0$ | 12.0$ | 2022/06/22 |

Any idea how this can be achieved ?

I've tried using temporary table, and do a JOIN but so far I always created just more rows...

Thank you for your answers.

### Solution

```sql
/****************************************************************************************************/
/* Create the example table */

drop table if exists #table
create table #table (
     ID int identity (1,1)
    ,Account nvarchar(100)
    ,Value decimal(6,2)
    ,Date date
    )

insert into #table values ( 'John', 23.0,   '2022/06/22')
insert into #table values ( 'Travis', 14.0, '2022/06/22')
insert into #table values ( 'John', 85.0,   '2022/06/22')
insert into #table values ( 'John', 125.0,  '2022/06/23')
insert into #table values ( 'John', 15.5,   '2022/06/23')
insert into #table values ( 'John', 17.5,   '2022/06/23')
insert into #table values ( 'John', 1.5,    '2022/06/23')
insert into #table values ( 'Travis',12.0,  '2022/06/22')

/****************************************************************************************************/
/* Create the output table by adding columns based on the maximum number of Values ​​per Account and Date */

drop table if exists #values
create table #Values (id int identity(1,1), Value nvarchar(100))
declare @position int = (select top 1 count(Value) from #table group by Account, Date order by 1 desc)
       ,@index int = 1
       ,@sql nvarchar(max) = ''

while (@position > @index - 1)
    begin
        insert into #Values values ('Value' + cast(@index as nvarchar(10)))
        set @sql = @sql + ', [Value' + cast(@index as nvarchar(10)) + '] decimal (10,2)'
        set @index = @index + 1
    end

drop table if exists ##table_output
exec('create table ##table_output ([id] int identity (1,1), [Account] nvarchar(100)' + @sql + ', [Date] date)')

/****************************************************************************************************/
/* Insert into table_output values grouping by Account and Date */

declare @Account as nvarchar(400)
       ,@values nvarchar(max) = ''
       ,@numberColumns int 
       ,@columnsName nvarchar(max) = ''
       ,@date date
       
declare c cursor for select distinct Account from #table
open c
fetch next from c into @Account
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        declare c_date cursor for select distinct date from #table where Account = @Account
        open c_date
        fetch next from c_date into @date
        while @@fetch_status = 0
            begin
                set @numberColumns = (select count(Value) from #table where Account = @Account and Date = @date)
                set @sql = 'select top ' + cast(@numberColumns as nvarchar(100)) + ' Value as columnName into ##columnsNameTable from #Values order by 1 asc'
                exec (@sql)
                set @values = (select string_agg(Value,', ') from #table where Account = @Account and Date = @date)
                set @columnsName = (select string_agg(columnName, ', ') from ##columnsNameTable)
                set @sql = 'insert into ##table_output (Account, ' + @columnsName + ', Date) values (''' + @Account + ''', ' + @values + ' , ''' + cast(@date as nvarchar(10)) + ''')'
                exec (@sql)
                fetch next from c_date into @date
                drop table if exists ##columnsNameTable 
            end
        close c_date
        deallocate c_date
    fetch next from c into @Account
    end
close c
deallocate c

/****************************************************************************************************/

select * from ##table_output order by 1, 3
```

Comment: Can someone only ever have **two** (or one) rows? If not, how many *can* they have?

Comment: @Larnu you can have more rows than just two for one person, the intended result is to have as many Value columns there is for 1 account.

Comment: I've been trying to implement different solutions, but the one you linked @Charlieface doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for, I'm looking at it maybe it's the solution. I will keep updated. Thank you guys !

Comment: What about it is not right? Can you not just assign a `ROW_NUMBER` in a subquery (derived table) and then conditionally aggregate over that?